# C# InvokeScript gives error 80020006

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-7.1

I have the piece of code as follows.

```
webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "alert('hey')");
```

It gives `An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006`. Could you guide how to rectify this error.

Comment: Have you tried sending an array object (containing one item, the string `alert('hey')` instead of the string itself) in the second parameter of `InvokeScript`?

Comment: @RedPolygon yes.same error.

Comment: Try calling `InvokeScript` when the `WebBrowser` raises the `Navigated` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in browser `window.alert` in Windows Phone, but you can bind one as follows to call `WebBrowser.ScriptNotify`

```
//inside the page
window.alert = function (__msg) { window.external.notify(' + __msg + '); };


// in your C# code
this.webBrowser.ScriptNotify += new EventHandler<NotifyEventArgs>(Browser_ScriptNotify);
void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(e.Value);
}

//later 
this.CordovaView.Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
this.CordovaView.Browser.InvokeScript("alert", "ok");
```

On Cordova, there is also a Notification Plugin that you can plug by

```
window.alert = navigator.notification.alert;
```

Just be sure to enable Notification Plugin in config.xml

```
  <feature name="Notification">
      <param name="wp-package" value="Notification"/>
  </feature>
```

Comment: the main task is not to call alert but window.localStorage.clear(); Your code was helpful and not giving any errors. But localstorage.clear() is not clearing the localstorage.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by race condition. What we need to do is

> this.CordovaView.Browser.LoadCompleted += Browser_LoadCompleted;

then

> ```
>   void Browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
>     {
>         this.CordovaView.Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
>         this.CordovaView.CordovaBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
>         this.CordovaView.Browser.InvokeScript("setPushToken", push_uri);
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thanks pal, really helped me